# Need help debugging a crash in my SpriteKit app

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

[image]

If I click to go to another scene then my app crashes.

Comment: Why are you conditional-setting 2 properties of `physicsBody` and then you are setting a new `SKPhysicsSprite` (losing the previous values)?

Comment: can you explain for me ? @appzYourLife

Comment: He's saying that the line "cUm.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody..." should be first right after you change the background color. In other words, you're changing properties of an SKPhysicsNode? and then you create a whole new object and overrides all previous code. You have to create the object first.

Comment: How Can I Fix This ERROR ? please help me

Answer (score 0):

Put the error line after the position line.

```
cUm.position....
cUm.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(...
cUm.physicsBody.dynamic...
....
```

You need to do this for all ur bodies. Always create your physics body first, and than set the properties such as dynamic etc.